How to print only subject and description in the grafana alert notification with Microsoft Teams using grafana alert notification template
I have created the following notification template in grafana dashboard.
{{ define "test_template" }}
    {{ if gt(len .Alerts.Firing) 0 }}
        {{ range .Alerts }}
            **subject**: {{ .Annotations.summary }}
            **description**: {{ .Annotations.description }}
        {{ end }}
    {{ else }}
            **subject**: issue_resolved
            **description**: issue_resolved
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}       

In the Microsoft teams contact point settings, I am trying to parse,
the value of the subject key in test_template in Title section and
value of the description key in test_template in Message section but I am receiving any empty message in the microsoft teams.
Now, how to parse the subject and description fields of test_template named notification template accurately in contact point settings of the grafana alerting ?
